# Removing items from a UITableView without using edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to delete rows in an array without having to use the edit function that Apple provide (Something along the lines of `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`). So the user selects some of the rows, presses a button **not** in the table view, then those rows fade away. Apple provide something of sorts [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html).

The code I am using calls an array of rows to be deleted, which is defined elsewhere, removes the array population objects at those particular rows, and is supposed to remove all of the rows using the fade stuff.

```
- (void) deleteTableRow {

NSIndexPath *current;
NSLog(@"to be deleted: %@", toBeDeleted); //toBeDeleted is the array with the NSIndexPath items

for(int i=0; i < [toBeDeleted count]; i++) {
    current = [toBeDeleted objectAtIndex: i];

    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:current.row]; //Remove the necessary array stuff

}
tv = [UITableView alloc];
[tv beginUpdates];
[tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:toBeDeleted withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tv endUpdates];
    // Do whatever data deletion you need to do...
```

}

**tv** is defined in my header file and is a referencing outlet of my UITableView.

So here are my main questions:

- Because my UITableView is not a UITableViewController (it is part of the view instead), **is this even possible?**
- If it is possible, **why** is this not working?

Comment: Why are you doing this **tv = [UITableView alloc];** ? Should you not be referencing your tableView? Such as **self.myTableView**

Comment: Re is it possible, yes it is.

Comment: Ah.. that seemed to do the trick. That was silly. Thanks very much.